# How can I compose a LINQ query with the help of a predicate builder

Tags: c#, linq, predicate, query-builder

I actually wanted to share this piece of code as I think it is of great use.

So, think that you want to programtically create a linq query.

It would be very nice to have that in a readable format, would it not?

We could create code like this:

```
PredicateBuilder<Document> filter = new PredicateBuilder<Document>();
filter.Add(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
filter.Add(x => x.IsArchive == false);

if (ucSearch.SearchText != "")
    filter.Add(x => x.DocumentName.Contains(ucSearch.SearchText));
repository.GetAll().Where(filter.GetLambda()).ToList();
```

Comment: There's already a convenient library for this called [Linqkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) actually, but using your code is more lightweight I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did not know of that.

Answer (score 0):

The code can be achieved with the help of a helper class like the one below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;

namespace Extensions
{
    public class PredicateBuilder<T> : List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>
    {
        private class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            private readonly ParameterExpression _parameter;
            public ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter)
            {
                _parameter = parameter;
            }
            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            {
                return base.VisitParameter(_parameter);
            }
        }
        public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetLambda()
        {
            if (this.Count > 0)
            {
                var type = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
                if (this.Count > 1)
                {
                    BinaryExpression binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.And,
                        new ParameterReplacer(type).Visit(this.First().Body),
                        new ParameterReplacer(type).Visit(this.Skip(1).First().Body));
                    if (this.Count > 2)
                    {
                        foreach (var ex in this.ToList().Skip(2))
                            binaryExpression = Expression.And(binaryExpression, new ParameterReplacer(type).Visit(ex.Body));
                    }
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, type);
                }
                else
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(new ParameterReplacer(type).Visit(this.First().Body), type);
            }
            return null;
        }
        public Func<T, bool> GetPredicate()
        {

            if (this.Count > 0)
            {
                var type = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
                if (this.Count > 1)
                {
                    BinaryExpression binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.And,
                        new ParameterReplacer(type).Visit(this.First().Body),
                        new ParameterReplacer(type).Visit(this.Skip(1).First().Body));
                    if (this.Count > 2)
                    {
                        foreach (var ex in this.ToList().Skip(2))
                            binaryExpression = Expression.And(binaryExpression, new ParameterReplacer(type).Visit(ex.Body));
                    }
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, type).Compile();
                }
                else
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(new ParameterReplacer(type).Visit(this.First().Body), type).Compile();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this just builds `And` criteria, which is equivalent of chaining multiple `.Where`.